# What is wrong with the for loop that is trying to get input from user?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, cin, getline

What is wrong with the for loop that is getting cname and camount from the user.

Here is my input:

size = 3

Name = "Asha R"

It throws me out of the loop and exits the program.  I should be able to enter 3 names and 3 amounts based on the size I entered in the first statement.

I've tried to change the cin statements several different ways, but nothing is working.  Your help is much appreciated:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct contribution {   
    string cname;
    double camount = 0.0;
};


int main ()
{
    int size = 0;
    
    //get array size from user
    cout << "How many members do you want to enter" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    
    //create dynamic array of contribution structure
    contribution * conarr = new contribution[size];

    //This is my problem area.  When I enter the 1st loop and enter "Asha R" it kicks out of the loop.  I tried to change the cin statements several different ways, but it's not working.  

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter name:  " ;
        //getline(cin, conarr[i].cname);
        getline(cin,conarr[i].cname).get();
       cout << "Enter contribution amount:  ";
      
       // cin >> conarr[i].camount;
       (cin >> conarr[i].camount).get();
    
    }
    
    delete[] conarr;
}
```

Comment: I included <iostream> and <string>

Comment: What's with the `.get()` calls, what are those for?